# Hiding current Object in Array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

right now I'm trying to hide an object in an array that is currently being displayed but the only way I could come up with hiding it was removing(using .remove()) the entire div that the array is appended to. I'm making a quiz using JavaScript so what I want is after the the user selects the a choice and is told if it is correct/Incorrect the current choices are removed and it goes onto the next question. Currently I have it removed and the next question appears but because I'm basically removing the div I can't get the next set of choices to appear. Just looking for some guidance as I am pretty new to JavaScript.

Thanks

```js
// Array of the questions, choices, and answers for the quiz.
var quizQuestions = [
    {
        question: "What method would you use to create a DOM object Element?", 
        choices: [".getAttribute()", ".createElement()", ".getElementById", ".setAttribute()"], 
        answer: ".createElement()"
    },
    {
        question: "What are variables used for?", 
        choices: ["Iterating over arrays", "Linking a JavaScript file to your html", "Storing data", "Performing specific tasks"], 
        answer: "Storing data"
    },
    {
        question: "When declaring a function, what comes after the keyword 'function'?", 
        choices: ["()", ";", "/", "++"], 
        answer: "()"
    }, 
    {
        question: "What would you use if you wanted to execute a block of code a set number of times?", 
        choices: ["While loop", "Math.random()", "For loop", "Switch statement"], 
        answer: "For loop"
    }, 
    {
        question: "Using the word 'break' will stop the code execution inside the switch block.", 
        choices: ["True", "False"], 
        answer: "True"
    }
];

// Buttons
var highScoresButtonEl = document.querySelector(".high-scores");
var startQuizEl = document.querySelector(".quiz-button");
var choicesButtonEl = document.querySelector(".choices");

var introTextEl = document.querySelector(".intro-text");
var questionsEl = document.querySelector(".questions");
var choicesEl = document.querySelector(".choices");
var answerEl = document.querySelector(".answer")
var timerEl = document.querySelector(".timer");

var choicesListEl = document.createElement("ul");
    choicesListEl.setAttribute("class", "choices");
    choicesEl.appendChild(choicesListEl);


// Button that starts the timer, displays the first question and the first set of choices.
startQuizEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector(".intro-text").style.visibility = "hidden";
    startQuizEl.style.visibility = "hidden";
    startTimer();
    
    
    
})
// When the any of the choices are clicked, the correct answer is displayed below them.
// choicesButtonEl.addEventListener("click", function () {
//     displayAnswer();

// })



choicesButtonEl.addEventListener("click", displayAnswer);


// Incriments each question in the array of objects.
var q = 0;
function displayQuestions () {
    questionsEl.textContent = quizQuestions[q].question;
    displayChoices();
}   

// Turns the choices from the array into an unordered list
function displayChoices () {
    for (i = 0; i < quizQuestions[q].choices.length; i++){
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = quizQuestions[q].choices[i];
        li.id = i
        choicesListEl.appendChild(li);
    }
    q++;
}

currentQuestion = 0;

// Takes answer from the array of objects and places it as a paragraph below the unordered list of choices.
 function displayAnswer (event) {
    console.log(event.target.textContent)
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    if (quizQuestions[currentQuestion].answer === event.target.textContent) {
        p.textContent = "Correct"
    } else {
        p.textContent = "Incorrect";
        startTime -= 8;
    }
    p.id = i
    answerEl.appendChild(p);

    setTimeout (function () {
        removeChoices();
        displayQuestions();
    }, 2000);

    currentQuestion++;
    
 }



 // Removes last set of choices/display of "Correct/Incorrect"

 function removeChoices () {
    choicesEl.remove();
    removeAnswer();

 }


 // Removes display of "Correct/Incorrect" from last question
 function removeAnswer () {
    answerEl.remove();
 }


 


 




 
// Styling for the li
// Click one of the buttons
// , the answer comes up and goes to next question


var startTime = 75;
var quizTime;
secondsElapsed = 0;

function startTimer() {
    
    timerEl.textContent = startTime;
    quizTime = setInterval(function () {
        if (startTime > 0){
        startTime--;
        timerEl.textContent = startTime;
        } else {
            endQuiz()
        }
    }, 1000);

    displayQuestions();
}

function endQuiz(){
    timerEl.textContent = "GAME OVER!"

    
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

header {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
     background-color: darkgray;
  
}

header ul {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style: none;
    
}

header ul li {
    padding: 5 px 5px;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.intro-text p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.intro-text h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
}


button {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 2px black;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.quiz-button:hover {
    background-color: darkgray;
}

.high-scores:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.quiz-content {
    text-align: center;
}

.choices ul li {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 2px black;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.choices ul li:hover {
    background-color: darkgray;
}

.questions {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.answer p {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Code-Quiz</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=".//assets/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <ul>
                <li><button class="high-scores" id="high-scores">High Scores</button></li>
                <li class="timer"></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="intro-text">
                <h1>Timed Coding Quiz</h1>
                <p>Come test your coding knowledge with this timed coding quiz! Everytime you answer a questoin incorrectly,
                    8 seconds is deducted from your total time! Good luck!</p>
        </main>
        </div>
        <section class="quiz-content">
            <button class="quiz-button" id="quiz-button" type="submit">Start Quiz</button>
            <div class="questions" id="questions"></div>
            <div class="choices" id="choices"></div>
            <div class="answer" id="answer"></div>
            <script src="../code-quiz/script.js"></script>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why put a test snippet if you don't present html and css code?

Comment: You can hide an element by setting its `style.display = 'none'`

Comment: @MisterJojo sorry, just did now.

Comment: this code can't work, I was able to click multiple answers on the first question